# Re-encoding a context vector after every step of decoding?

Tags: python, sequence, lstm, pytorch, encoder-decoder

I am currently working on a sequence model which aims to predict the head orientation of somebody watching VR for an arbitrary amount of frames in the future.

Using an encoder-decoder paradigm, a person's previous 100 frames of **head orientation** and the **video's previous 100 frames of data** are fed into an encoder to create a context.  *(100 is arbitrary here, but for sake of writing I will use 100 frames, so the previous sequence's data will be  [ T<sub>(-100)</sub> - T<sub>0</sub> ]   )*

The context is then fed into the decoder, and frame by frame outputting a probability distribution of where the viewer will be looking at *T<sub>1</sub>* for the first iteration of decoding, *T<sub>2</sub>* for the second iteration, *etc*.

The context vector therefore has a lot of weight on its shoulders, encoding data from the entire previous sequence.  So in order to help with the decoder's output, at each step of decoding I want to let the decoder have access to the **video's future 100 frames of data**.
So at time  *T<sub>2</sub>*, the decoder will be on its second iteration and have access to the 102<sub>nd</sub> video frame to use for convolution, saliency, etc.

The way we were thinking to accomplish this is to have the encoder re-encode the context vector on *each iteration* of decoding the context, and replacing the encoder's input to contain the **future video frame data**.

So for example on the second iteration of decoding, we would re-encode the context, but replace the data for *T<sub>(-100)</sub>* with the decoded output for *T<sub>1</sub>*, and the video frame for *T<sub>(-100)</sub>* with the video frame for *T<sub>2</sub>*.  We would continue to iterate through decoding in this way.

The thought is this would be a way to provide the decoder with information about the *upcoming* video, and use its previous predictions to enforce the integrity of future predictions of movement.  This idea of re-encoding the context was also presented by [Johannes Baptist from the University of Amsterdam in this paper](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=2ahUKEwj_-tralO3cAhWLwFkKHToqDZAQFjAAegQIABAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fesc.fnwi.uva.nl%2Fthesis%2Fcentraal%2Ffiles%2Ff579353583.pdf&usg=AOvVaw2pk52J2CSN0Y3aKg62QV6L), though I am an undergraduate student and still new to this field, so the paper was a bit challenging to grasp.

If anybody has any intuition on what re-encoding the context at every step of decoding will do to an encoder-decoder model, and can provide any insight or resources to continue looking into, that would be great, thank you very much.